# How to get count of child table items which is in csv string format

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I have Packages, Services tables. ServiceIds are included in the Packages table as comma-separated string like below,

Services Table:

```
|ID|Service Name|
|--|------------|
|1|Service A|
|2|Service B|
|3|Service C|
|4|Service D|
|5|Service E|
|8|Service G|
```

Package Table:

```
| ID | Package Name | Services |
|----|--------------|----------|
| 1  | Silver Plan  | 1,5,4,8  |
| 2  | Gold Plan  | 1,3,5,8  |
```

**How can I show the Services table output along with the Packages count like below format in Entity Frame Work using LINQ?**

Expected Result:

```
|ID|Service Name|Packages|
|--|------------|--------|
|1|Service A| (2) Packages|
|2|Service B|(0) Packages|
|3|Service C|(1) Packages|
|4|Service D|(1) Packages|
|5|Service E|(2) Packages|
|8|Service G|(1) Packages|
```

I tried with the below LINQ,

```
using(var db=new DBContext())
{
  var output= (from s in db.services select new {s.ID,s.ServiceName,Packages= db.Packages.count(f=>??)}
).ToList();
)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution:

```
using(var db = new DBContext())
{ 
   var packages = db.Packages.Select(x => new { x.Services }).ToArray()
                          .Select(x => new { services = x.Services.Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s.Trim())).ToArray() })
                          .ToArray();
                          
   var output = (from s in db.Services         
                 select new {
                   s.ID,
                   s.ServiceName,           
                 }).ToArray()
                 .Select(x => new { 
                               x.ID, 
                               x.ServiceName, 
                               count = packages.Count(p => p.services.Any(s => s == x.ID) )
                        }).ToList();
}
```